# When I set an Enum instance variable as a value that is included as an option in the Enum class itself, it can not be resolved to a type.Why?

Tags: java, enums, instance

```
//Enum class

package model.cards;

public enum Rarity {
      BASIC, COMMON, RARE, EPIC, LEGENDARY}

//Different class

package model.cards.minions;
import model.cards.Rarity;

public class Icehowl {
    private int manaCost=9;
    private Rarity rarity=LEGENDARY; //error "LEGENDARY" can not be resolved to a variable
    private boolean attacked=true;
    private int maxHP=10;
}
```

Comment: You mean `Rarity.LEGENDARY`. The enum value `LEGENDARY` is a constant in the type `Rarity`.

Comment: Compiler doesn't know what `LEGENDARY` means, because you aren't importing it properly. You should do as khelwood said, or `import static Rarity.LEGENDARY;` at the top.

Comment: I didn't write it that way but that seems to be the right way to write it.

Comment: How come  when I have written it before differently and it worked??

Comment: How differently?

Comment: @husseljo Because that other time you were doing something different.

Comment: as written in code , not Rarity.LEGENDARY

Comment: So this means that in some different case it isnt written like that.

Comment: What case??????

Comment: We can't tell you why some other bit of code did some particular thing without seeing the code. We could guess but that's a really inefficient way to try and answer questions.

Comment: Yeah, you're right thanks guys

Comment: Appreciate the effort

Comment: It might've worked with original code if `Rarity` was an inner class of `Icehowl`. If you don't show the code where it worked though, we'd have as much of an idea of "why" as you do.

Answer (score 2):

You mean

```
private Rarity rarity = Rarity.LEGENDARY;
```

The enum value `LEGENDARY` is a constant in the type `Rarity`.